# Rails: AJAX not going to correct controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

routes.rb:

```
  get 'events/filter', :to => "events#filter"
```

controller:

```
def index
  ## some stuff
end

def filter
  binding.pry
end
```

AJAX call:

```
    $.get({
          url: "/events/filter",
          data: { from_date: "foo", until_date: "bar"},
          success: console.log("AJAX success")
        });
```

rake routes:

```
events_filter GET    /events/filter(.:format)          events#filter
```

I am making the above AJAX call and it is going to my events#index action. What am I missing?

Comment: may be try `url: events/filter` or make sure your `url:` has the right path.

Comment: Hmm.. just tried... Verified in rake routes: events_filter GET    /events/filter(.:format)          events#filter

Comment: NVM I had a before_filter authenticate which was redirecting to another controller action. sorry

Comment: Can you post the entire routes.rb , I need to know the route for index method.

Comment: Try changing `$.get` to `$.ajax` and `url: "/events/filter"` to `url: "events/filter"`.

Comment: Hey Sorry I actually resolved this issue. The problem was my events#filter had an before_action to authenticate_user in the controller. Removed that and issue was fixed. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my events#filter had an before_action to authenticate_user in the controller. Removed that and issue was fixed.